# how to create trainable weight variable for custom keras layer

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, layer

I am implementing custom average pooling layer, where each neuron computes the mean of its inputs, then multiplies the result by a learnable coefficient and adds a learnable bias term, then finally applies the activation function

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

from keras import backend as K


class Average_Pooling_Layer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dimension, **kwargs):
        super(Average_Pooling_Layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.output_dimension = output_dimension

    def build(self, input_shape):

        self.weights = self.add_weight(name='weights2',
                              shape=(input_shape[0], 
                               int(self.output_dimension[0]), 
                               int(self.output_dimension[1]), 
                               int(self.output_dimension[2])),
                               initializer='uniform',
                               trainable=True)
    super(Average_Pooling_Layer, self).build(input_shape)

   def call(self, inputs):
        return K.tanh((inputs * self.weights))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape)
```

Code Usage

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
stride = 1
c1 = model.add(Conv2D(6, kernel_size=[5,5], strides=(stride,stride), padding="valid", input_shape=(32,32,1), 
                  activation = 'tanh'))
s2_before_activation = model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
s2 = model.add(Average_Pooling_Layer(output_dimension = (14, 14, 6)))
```

I am getting error as "Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: (Dimension(None), 14, 14, 6). Consider casting elements to a supported type." "None" is batch size, which I am getting from previous layer.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is caused by the data type. `input_shape[0]` returns `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape.Dimension'>` instead of `int`.

You can replace `input_shape[0]` with `tf.TensorShape(input_shape).as_list()[0]`. But your data dimension is not right and you have to adjust and modify it according to your needs.

**Edit**

If you get error as "can't set attribute", you should rename your weight variable instead of `self.weights`. For example, change to `self.weights_new`.

Comment: still same error  "Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor. Contents: (None, 14, 14, 6). Consider casting elements to a supported type."

My output dimension is 14, 14, 6 - I think that is correct

Comment: @VamshiPulluri First, the shape of the layer weight should be independent of batch_size, so you shouldn't take an index of `[0]`. Second, What function do you want to achieve in `Average_Pooling_Layer`, and let it output is `(None, 14, 14, 6)` when your shape of `s2_before_activation` output is `(None, 16, 16, 6)`? So I think your data dimension is not right.

Comment: Thanks for second point. Edited it to include `valid` padding for `c1`. I am actually creating pooling layer for LeNet5 NN. The pooling layer's each neuron computes the mean of its inputs, then multiplies the result by a learnable coefficient and adds a learnable bias term, then finally applies the activation function. So, `s2_before_activation` calculates the `mean`. Now, `s2` multiplies the `learnable weighs` and adds the `bias` term (which is not yet aded in code)

Comment: And as for first point, When I keep shape as `shape=(int(self.output_dimension[0]), int(self.output_dimension[1]), int(self.output_dimension[2]))` in `build` method of `self.weighs` I am getting error as "can't set attribute"

Comment: @VamshiPulluri I have already answered this question in the answer.